# How can I see who has access to an individual's private github repo?

Tags: github

Say I was invited into a private repo owned by user account (and not an organizational account). Is it possible to see who else has access to that private repository (Assuming I was not granted admin permissions, if that's possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: A repository owned by a user account has two permission levels:

- the repository owner and
- collaborators.

Second, [Collaborator access on a repository owned by a user account](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/#collaborator-access-on-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account) involves:

> Open, close, re-open, and **assign issues**

So they should be able to see the list of collaborators for that private repo, if they want to assign an issue to one of its members.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking specifically for how / where can I see a list of collaborators?

Comment: @NirIzr For now, I only see that when assigning an issue, so this is a workaround.